# Merging 2 structures with different types

Tags: go

I have two structures.

- `EventForm` is the structure that is used to parse the `POST` body of a request.
- `EventTable` is used for creating the `MYSQL` table structure and finding/creating rows.

I want to merge `EventForm` with `EventTable` so that fields like `ID` cannot be overridden via the `POST` body. I am not able to convert the type of `EventForm` to `EventTable` since you cannot convert a struct to a different type if the fields do not 100% match. So my question is what is the best way to merge these two structs? If it is not plausible to merge these two structs how could I best solve this problem?

```
package models

import "time"

// EventTable table structure of "events"
type EventTable struct {
    EventForm `xorm:"extends"`
    ID        int       `xorm:"autoincr pk 'id'" json:"id"`
    Created   time.Time `xorm:"not null created" json:"created"`
    Updated   time.Time `xorm:"not null updated" json:"updated"`
}

// TableName table name of EventTable
func (u *EventTable) TableName() string {
    return "events"
}

// EventForm the structure that is received via an API call
type EventForm struct {
    Title       string `xorm:"not null" json:"title" required:"true"`
    Description string `xorm:"not null" json:"description" required:"true"`
    Owner       string `xorm:"not null" json:"owner" required:"true"`
    Lat         string `xorm:"not null" json:"lat" required:"true"`
    Lng         string `xorm:"not null" json:"lng" required:"true"`
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Do you want only one type instead of two, e.g. `Event`? Is embedding, which is what you already use, not enough? If so, how? What do you need that embedding doesn't provide?

Answer (score 0):

I am with @mkopriva and don't fully understand what the problem is.  Assuming you are receiving EventForm from some API call

```
evtForm := GetSomeEventForm()
evtTable := &models.EventTable{ EventForm: evtForm, Created: time.Now() }
someORMProbably.Insert(evtTable)
```